# Custom font displayed wrong only on pre-Lollipop devices

Tags: android, textview, android-5.0-lollipop, custom-font, android-typeface

I am using custom font in my app and one of the supported languages is Vietnamese (Same issue occurs with Greek).

Some characters are displayed wrong and my observation is that this only happens on pre-Lollipop devices. I tested this on various device models and emulators and in all instances the issue was only present with pre-Lollipop devices. This does not seem like encoding issue since I've logged the string before calling setText on the TextView and all characters are displayed correctly both in Debug and Monitor window.

```
    String title = "Thị trường chứng khoán: Đồng loạt giảm cổ phiếu";
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getResources().getAssets(),"Font/Merriweather-Bold.ttf");
    textView.setTypeface(font);
    textView.setText(title);
```

Any clues ? Thanks in advance.

Custom font used is **Merriweather-Bold.ttf**

- **Screenshot 1**: HTC Evo - 4.3 (API 18) - Custom font (Merriweather-Bold)
- **Screenshot 2**: Google Nexus 5 - 5.1.0 (API 22) - Custom font (Merriweather-Bold)
- **Screenshot 3**: HTC Evo - 4.3 (API 18) - Default (System) font

[image: HTC Evo 4.3 (API 18)]

[image: Google Nexus 5 - 5.1.0 (API-22) (]

[image: Default (System) font is fine on both]

Comment: Try downloading `OTF` Instead of `TTF`.. Am not sure about it. But it's worth giving a shot.

Comment: I just tried this but had no luck, issue is still there

Comment: did you test this library ? https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy